# Multcomp: glht for p-value point estimate

Tags: r, glm, poisson

Anyone have any idea of how to get the p-value for a specific point estimate using glht() in R.

I have the below model:

```
Glm(outcome ~ Quarter + intervention + time, family = Poisson)
```

I want to know the p-value and confidence intervals at point estimate Q=20 and think you can do so using glht, but have no idea how.

Comment: Just to be clear: You are talking about a p-value from testing whether the point estimate at Quarter 20 is significantly different from 0?

Comment: We're testing whether the point estimate at Quarter 20 is signficiantly different from the counterfactual Quarter 20 [extrapolation of pre-intervention trend].